# Trouble with regex in asp.net textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Hi guys I'm creating a simple register form and I have a little problem with `pattern` TAG. I want check my textbox hasn't quotation marks.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtpassword" name="password" runat="server" placeholder="Password" TextMode="Password" required pattern=""" ></asp:TextBox>
```

But compiler says to me that the server' s tag is incorrect. How can I solve this problem?

If it's possible I want use pattern TAG.
Sincerely,
TInwor

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript library that leverages the `pattern` attribute to validate the input?

Comment: And what do you mean when you say you want to use pattern TAG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Problem is `server' s tag is incorrect`

Try this instead of your code `pattern="""` to `pattern="'"`

Lool like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtpassword" name="password" runat="server" placeholder="Password" 

TextMode="Password" required pattern="'" ></asp:TextBox>
```

> dude, You can solve it easily from the message :)